# Why is the property added outside his parent in Object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular11

I have an Interface declared like this:

**Sejour.ts**

```
import { SejourItem } from './SejourItem';
export interface Sejour {
    dsAdvSejour: DsAdvSejour;
}

interface DsAdvSejour {
    'prods:hasChanges': any;
    ttSejour: SejourItem[];
    'prods:before': any;
}
```

which contains an Array of SejourItem :

**SejourItem.ts**

```
export interface SejourItem {
    'prods:rowState'?: string;
    ROWID: string;
    Sequence: number;
    NoSejour: string;
    NomPatient: string;
    NoPatient: string;
    DateNaissance: Date | string;
    SexePatient: string;
    CodePostal: string;
    OrgAssur1: string;
    Statut: string;
    DateDebutSejour: Date | string;
    DateFinSejour: Date | string;
    CodeReadmission: string;
    Adresse: string;
    MotifAdmissionAdm: string;
    CodeAdresseParAdm: string;
    TypeSortieAdm: string;
    CodeDestinationAdm: string;
    TypePatient: string;
    TypeAdmission: string | null;
    TypeSejour: number;
    CodePays: string;
    HeureDebutSejour: string;
    HeureFinSejour: string;
    MinuteDebutSejour: string;
    MinuteFinSejour: string;
    SejourCloture: boolean;
    NumerosPrestataires: string;
    CodeNationalite: string;
    NoSejourMaman: string;
    SiteAdmission: string;
    LieuAvantAdmission: string;
    NbJoursReadmission: string;
    CodeAssociation: string;
    TypeAssociation: string;
    CodeAssurabiliteRHM: string;
    PatientVIP: string;
}
```

As you can see, I have an optional property called `prods:rowState`.

This value can be **created**, **updated**, or **deleted**.

I have a simple function, handling these cases :

```
private prepareBody(stayToPrepare: SejourItem, query: string, stayBefore?: SejourItem): Sejour {
        query = query.toUpperCase();
        let preparedStay: Sejour = {} as Sejour;
        switch (query) {
            case 'POST':
                stayToPrepare['prods:rowState'] = 'created';
                preparedStay = {
                    dsAdvSejour: {
                        'prods:hasChanges': true,
                        ttSejour: [stayToPrepare],
                        'prods:before': {},
                    },
                };
                break;
            //Other cases...
        }
        return preparedStay;
    }
```

So when I want to achieve a post request, it defined the `prods:rowState` to 'created', and returns a clean Sejour object which I post to my back-end.

Here's my problem:

When I just `console.log(JSON.stringify(preparedState, null, 2))`, this is what I get :

```
{
  "dsAdvSejour": {
    "prods:hasChanges": true,
    "ttSejour": [
      {
        "sejourItem": { // Why do I have a key ? I was added in an array...
          "ROWID": "",
          "Sequence": 0,
          "NoSejour": "",
          "NomPatient": "",
          "NoPatient": "",
          "DateNaissance": "2021-03-30",
          "SexePatient": "",
          "CodePostal": "",
          "OrgAssur1": "",
          "Statut": "",
          "DateDebutSejour": "2021-03-30",
          "DateFinSejour": "2021-03-30",
          "CodeReadmission": "",
          "Adresse": "",
          "MotifAdmissionAdm": "",
          "CodeAdresseParAdm": "",
          "TypeSortieAdm": "",
          "CodeDestinationAdm": "",
          "TypePatient": "",
          "TypeAdmission": "",
          "TypeSejour": 0,
          "CodePays": "",
          "HeureDebutSejour": "0",
          "HeureFinSejour": "0",
          "MinuteDebutSejour": "0",
          "MinuteFinSejour": "0",
          "SejourCloture": false,
          "NumerosPrestataires": "",
          "CodeNationalite": "",
          "NoSejourMaman": "",
          "SiteAdmission": "",
          "LieuAvantAdmission": "",
          "NbJoursReadmission": "",
          "CodeAssociation": "",
          "TypeAssociation": "",
          "CodeAssurabiliteRHM": "",
          "PatientVIP": ""
        },
        "prods:rowState": "created" // Why am I added here ? I'm a SejourItem property...
      }
    ],
    "prods:before": {}
  }
}
```

As long as I totally don't get why this happens, I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hpiqsv?file=index.ts) with similar instructions. And I don't understand, even more, why it is working properly in the stackblitz.

Does anyone understand what happens ? If yes, I would be glad to know what I'm missing here.

*PS : My code is initially running in an Angular 11 project, if this can help.*

*Edit: My first thought is a TypeScript bug, as long as I can't reproduce the behaviour in a StackBlitz, using the same code*

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log` the value of the `stayToPrepare` parameter at the beginning of the `prepareBody` function? My guess is that the content of that parameter does not match the declared type (your code does not show how the value of that parameter is obtained).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the incoming `stayToPrepare` parameter isn't of type `SejourItem` but instead `{ sejourItem: SejourItem }`.

Best approach is of course to fix this prior invoking `prepareBody`. Perhaps something like:

```
this.prepareBody(stayToPrepare.sejourItem, query, stayBefore)
```

Please confirm if I assume correctly.

Comment: Your assumption was correct. The stayToPrepate input was of type `{ sejourItem: SejourItem }`, giving an unwanted result from the `prepareBody()` function. Thanks for your help, with this fix it is working fine.